Crear función de suma que puedas introducir los números que sean
estoy empezando a programar en python. Estoy tratando de crear una función para un paquete que estoy creando de todas las operaciones matemáticas para que las pueda usar y no tener que estar metiendo el código cada vez.
He empezado a crear el programa y al tratar de hacer la suma me da un error que es este: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'.
def suma():
cuantos_sum=int(input("Escribe cuantos números quieres sumar: "))
resultado_sum=[]
for i in range(cuantos_sum):
    num_sum=int(input("Ingrese el número de la suma: "))
    resultado_sum.append(str(num_sum))
resultado_sum=sum(str(resultado_sum))
return "El resultado de la suma es: " + str(suma)

Y en los programas en los que lo voy a usar en el código escribiré print(suma())

Dentro del FOR estas parseando el entero ingresado a un String [resultado_sum.append(str(num_sum))]. Como vas a sumarle a un entero un String? Si vas a agregar tus valores a la lista resultado_sum, todos deben ser valores enteros tal cual los recibes. Parsea a String solo para la salida por pantalla.

No pongas [cerrado] en el título, o cuslquier otra cosa parecida. Una pregunta "cerrada" tiene otro significado en el sitio, que no implica que haya sido resuelta o solucionada.

La lista de valores ingresados debe guardarlos como enteros, no como string
def suma():
    cuantos_sum=int(input("Escribe cuantos números quieres sumar: "))
    resultado_sum=[]
    for i in range(cuantos_sum):
        num_sum=int(input("Ingrese el número de la suma: "))
        resultado_sum.append(num_sum)

    resultado_sum=sum(resultado_sum)
    return "El resultado de la suma es: " + str(resultado_sum)

La operación str(suma) es incorrecta, ya que suma es el nombre de la función. Lo correcto es str(resultado_sum)

Ya me funciona, gracias. No me di cuenta de ese error que puse sin querer.

@Adr_868, si la respuesta te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, por favor, considera marcarla como aceptada. Más info ¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?

Esta es otra opción:
Yo definiria una función generica "get_input" para entrada de datos, puesto que la funcion para sumar ya existe:
def get_input(n_count):
  a_out=[] ### el arreglo de salida (una lista de python)
  for i in range(n_count):  ### captura datos
     n_data=int(input("Ingrese el número de la suma: "))
     a_out.append(n_data) ### agrega al array el dato capturado
  return(a_out) ### retorna el arreglo lleno
  

Se usaría asi:
La funcion definida "get_input" sólo obtiene las entradas, ya despés to haces lo que quieras con los datos:
### Uso:
cuantos_sum=int(input("Escribe cuantos números quieres sumar: "))
a_input=get_input(cuantos_sum)
print("suma:",sum(a_input))
print("max:",max(a_input))
print("min:",min(a_input))

Ejemplo de salida:
Escribe cuantos números quieres sumar: 3
Ingrese el número de la suma: 4
Ingrese el número de la suma: 5
Ingrese el número de la suma: 2
suma: 11
max: 5
min: 2

